# Extract field from xml file with weather

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Have an XML file with struct like

```
<codes>
    <condition>
        <code>395</code>
        <description>Moderate or heavy snow in area with thunder</description>
        <day_icon>wsymbol_0012_heavy_snow_showers</day_icon>
        <night_icon>wsymbol_0028_heavy_snow_showers_night</night_icon>
    </condition>
    <condition>
        <code>392</code>
        <description>Patchy light snow in area with thunder</description>
        <day_icon>wsymbol_0016_thundery_showers</day_icon>
        <night_icon>wsymbol_0032_thundery_showers_night</night_icon>
    </condition>
</codes>
```

How to write function, thats will response description only by code

as a func(395) return @Moderate or heavy snow in area with thunder@

Comment: Any code you've attempted so far?

Comment: Look into JDOM. I just tried it yesterday, and it's pretty easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use a regex to extract the value. Its fast and efficient (why parse everything into memory (dom).

```
public static String extractDescription(String code, String xmlData){
        //search for the entire condition element based on the id
        Pattern elementPattern=Pattern.compile("<condition><code>"+code+"</code><description>(.*?)</description>.*</condition>");

        Matcher elementMatcher=elementPattern.matcher(xmlData);

        if(elementMatcher.groupCount()>0){//if we have some groups to match in our pattern
            if(elementMatcher.find()){//find the matches
                return elementMatcher.group(1);
            }
            else{//no match found
                return null;
            }
        }
        else{//our pattern is useless and does not contain any groups to match
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The only heavy operation here is the Pattern.compile(..) but its still pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following XPath:

```
/codes/condition[code='395']/description/text()
```

Here's an example of using XPath in java: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html